# Sublime Text 2 PHP Else autocompletes a function

Tags: php, sublimetext2

When I type `else` and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, Sublime inserts `printer_draw_elipse(printer_handle, ul_x, ul_y, lr_x, lr_y)`. How do I avoid this, and make it only insert the Tab character?

I noticed the file with the path `~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/PHP/php-else.sublime-snippet`, but removing that had no effect.

Comment: Did you restart sublime text after removing the snippet file?

Comment: I hadn't done that, but I just tried and it didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the unfortunate result of partial-text matching and autocomplete. The way I've gotten past it is to add the following line to the end of the completions list in **~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/PHP/PHP.sublime-completions** (after the **zlib_get_coding_type** trigger, though you can place it anywhere in that list of triggers and it will work):

```
{ "trigger": "else", "contents": "else  " }
```

Essentially, we're short-circuiting the autocomplete with our own snippet that just replaces the "else"+TAB sequence with "else" and a trailing tab.